# HTML to React Conversion blockholes

Tags: reactjs

I have been asked to convert a HTML file to react components.I have used html to jsx compiler. It's a huge file of about 1005 lines of code hence I'm unable to upload the file.

I'm unable to render css and local images even on following the proper syntax.

Synatx followed is something like this

```
img src={require('./resources/cut.svg')} width={30} height={20}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the items eg image folder at the top and then referencing that in react ?

Also this seems to be what you are doing: [How to convert a html template to react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370369/how-to-convert-a-html-template-to-react)

Comment: Yes I have tried importing the images. And you are correct i tried out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370369/how-to-convert-a-html-template-to-react